# Android: Can't delete an item in Listview because of PrimaryKey

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to delete an item in a listview when a button is clicked. I can't do it because the primary key to all items are the same (zero). The primary key is _id and it's an autoincrement value.
When I insert an item the id isn't incremented and when I try to get it from database it returns to all objects id=0. I tried to get other attributes from the object and they are also correct.
Why it returns always zero?

**My code:**

```
(...)
.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {

Des desp=list.get(position);
Log.d("DEBUG","category:"+desp.getCategory());
Log.d("DEBUG","Id:"+desp.getID());

databaseHelper.deleteDes(desp.getID());
notifyDataSetChanged();
dialogInterface.dismiss();
}
```

**My classe Des:**

```
public class Des{
public Des()
    {}

public int getID() {
        return id_desp;
(...)
}
}
```

**Creation of Table:**

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EXAMPLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_EXAMPLE + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + col_CATEGORY + " TEXT,"
            + col_DATA_CRIACAO + " DATETIME,"
            + col_DATA_MODIF + " DATETIME,"
            + FOREIGN_KEY
            + ");";
```

**Part of the method to insert in the table:**

```
    (...)
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(col_CATEGORY, des.getCategory());
    values.put(col_DATA_CRIACAO, strDate);
    values.put(col_DATA_MODIF, strDate);

    long id =db.insert(TABLE_EXAMPLE, null ,values);
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: if your id is an auto-increment value then how can it be 0 ... check your db code

Comment: Pobably, List view is not related to your question, please improve your question and create a minimal working example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you add the code you use to fetch your object from db?

Comment: @ashish.n what should I check? When I insert an item I use "db.insert(TABLE_EXAMPLE, null ,values);" with ContentValues. I'm sure this is correct..I have update my question with more code.

Comment: By definition, your primary key **can not** be 0 on all your items. I'm guessing that something is wrong when you are trying to read your entries from the database.